# React unmounting 30k+ components is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a Map with around 30k+ interactive markers and a number of filters for them. Whenever I select a filter and click apply an API call is made to get the filtered data. Now the problem is the existing 30k+ markers will removed(unmounted) and will be replaced with the new filtered data from the api call. This unmount operation causes the UI to freeze for around 10+ seconds and finally it renders the filtered data. I am unable to even show a spinner when such an operation takes place.

How to optimize mounting and unmounting of such a large data set ?. I've used all rendering optimizations like React.memo() and such but the problem is due to the initial render and removal of such a large data at once.

```
`<Map
     ref={mapRef}
     center={latlng}
     zoom={14}
     minZoom={12}
     preferCanvas={true}
  >
  <TileLayer
      attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">OSM</a>'
      url={`${OSM_URL}/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`}
   />
   <MarkerClusterGroup chunkedLoading={true} chunkInterval={500}>
       <MarkerList markers={mydata} showInfoPopup={showInfoPopup} />
    </MarkerClusterGroup>
</Map>`
```

Things I've considered:

1. Using `display: none` rather than unmount. But this won't solve the issue the initial mount and its not possible for the marker components.
2. Offload rendering to a Worker thread. (Don't know if this is possible in React - best way)
3. Use plain old DOM elements rather than React Components but this doesn't feel optimal

Any guidance on how to handle such a large data set is much appreciated.

Comment: could you only unmount what has changed and not all of the data? Also I think you could show the spinner before the operation starts and then remove the spinner once the operation has completed.

Comment: Well what has changed is the entire dataset. Also spinner can only be shown in case of an async operation which is not. The problem is with mounting and unmounting a large number of components which unfortunately has to happen. I'm looking for ways to unblock the UI thread.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the `MarkerList` in a conditional which would unmount all of it if mydata becomes falsy? Something like `{ mydata && <MarkerList markers={mydata} showInfoPopup={showInfoPopup} /> }` perhaps, or check the length of mydata.

Comment: In the end you are still unmounting everything right? That will still block the UI thread

Comment: I believe that's true; the work to the virtual DOM will stay have to get done.

I just found a reference to "chunking" which could be helpful. http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/#chunked-addlayers-options

Comment: I've already used the above chunking mechanism as you can see in the above code snippet. I think it's more of a React issue rather than a Map one

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. ‍♂️ I suspect you're right. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas except maybe using a Leaflet filter plugin, or partitioning your data by the possible filters and putting them on different layers.

Comment: Thanks Jon for looking at this. I am out of ideas as well. I feel it's a hard problem to solve which digs deeper into React's handling of large of amount of data. If this was a list I can paginate the data or use windowing techniques but unfortunately that's not the case here. Just wish we could do a non-blocking render somehow

Comment: One of the out-of-the-box ideas would be to never render 30k+ elements. Rather, if the filtering returns more than say 1k+ elements, you render the first 1k+ and leave an indication to the user that only top 1k+ elements were rendered and the user needs to make the filtering more specific. This makes sense, imagine your dataset is 30k+ today but will grow to 1m+ someday. Would you still try to render it?

Comment: Is ```MarkerList``` your custom component or coming from the library you're using? Maybe it won't help much, but still libraries handling big lists like ```react-window```, for instance, usually have a way to identify an item between renders with some option provided by the API. In case of the latter one, there was ```itemKey``` prop which returns unique ID for a row to avoid re-mounting on subsequent renders (probably it uses the ```key``` attribute of React internally). Maybe this library ```react-leaflet``` has something similar?

Comment: Of course, it would depend how much markers actually need to be removed and how much should stay upon filtering. Say, if you have 10k markers visible and filter results are just 1k of them, the above won't help much I guess...

Comment: If only that was possible with the current requirement @WiktorZychla. I suggested the same to no avail.

Comment: @RosenDimov there doesn't seem to anything similar to windowing for the map. Yeah I agree that won't help much. I just wonder how other orgs handle this kind of data in production

Comment: Hm, I don't know which of the components in the code you're showing are your own and which are third-party, and if they are, how much they are customizable... But libraries like ```react-three-fiber``` actually use a different approach than just using the traditional Virtual DOM (I don't know if it's used at all in this library) and that way achieve high performance. With it, it shouldn't be an issue destroying/creating big amount of objects in a fast manner, but an issue might be integrating it with ```react-leaflet```. That is, drawing markers with RTF and integrating them with RL.

Comment: Sounds like a known issue of react-leaflet-markercluster, not being able to use bulk adding after initial rendering. Have you tried the workaround proposed in [react-leaflet-markercluster issue #76 (comment)](https://github.com/yuzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster/issues/76#issuecomment-440247126)?

Comment: @RosenDimov `react-three-fiber` seems interesting. I'm thinking what approach did they take. Also is there some way to immediately unmount the component? Currently what seems to happen is React traverses through all the Marker nodes and unmounts them one by one. If I could unmount the Parent component in one shot without even traversing the marker components then at least the unmount issue will be solved. But I'm not sure if such a technique exists

Comment: @ghybs I'll check that out

Comment: *Currently what seems to happen is React traverses through all the Marker nodes and unmounts them one by one.* - not an expert in the library I mentioned, but I'm almost certain that this is not what happens there. :D From what I've read in different posts, it just avoids the work that the Virtual DOM does (uses different reconciler), which changes things a lot.

Comment: @RosenDimov I was referring to how React works normally there.

Comment: Yes, I understood, just mentioning that ```react-three-fiber``` shouldn't have this overhead of mount/remount, it uses different approach under the hood. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the clearLayers method of Leaflet.js to clear all the marker nodes. This fixed the mount and unmount slowness.